# How to drop temporary files inside Popcorn Time?

Tags: 18.04, memory-usage, cache

Using Popcorntime I usually find one issue, when I try to find a film or some series or after I've watched 2 films, Popcorntime inform me a system error telling me that I haven't memory enough to report it.

I have always to restart my computer but I've tried another solutions too.

I've fixed my cache pressure to 50.

When that bug is reported I use this two commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

to erase my temprary files and

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

to drop my cache...

This didn't fix the issue...

I left you here my output from

```
 free
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        2031976     1245216      295140      120740      491620      520592
Swap:       2097148      121600     1975548
```

And my output from

```
df-h
```

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            963M     0  963M   0% /dev
tmpfs           199M  1,7M  197M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       146G  9,6G  129G   7% /
tmpfs           993M   19M  974M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           993M     0  993M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop0       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop1       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop3       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop5      2,4M  2,4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/199
/dev/loop6       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop8       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop10      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop13      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop14     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop15      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop7      2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop17     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop11     2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/222
/dev/loop12      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop9      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop16      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop4       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
tmpfs           199M   16K  199M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           199M   28K  199M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I have popcorn time configured to drop temporary files when I close it but it actually dosen't drop anything until I restart my computer.

My question is:

Can I erase temporary files stored in temporary files folder inside Popcorntime without restarting my pc?

I don't know if I have explained my problem properly, if anyone think that I have to express it another way I will gladly accept any help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not using a hard disk or is it full? Popcorn Time (or any other application) should be saving files to a disk not your RAM.

Comment: Yes I am using a hard disk ubuntu 18.04.1 I am going to edit my question adding my df -h output... just in case...

Comment: And of course it should be that way but therefore is my question, I don't think popcorn is using cache I don't know why it keep telling me ther is no memory enough to report a bug... that is the question...